# How to show Bengali text properly

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextfield, jtextarea

I have a `JTextArea` where I need to show Bengali text like:

> বাংলাদেশ

But all I can see is rectangular boxes. How can I show Bengali characters properly?

Comment: +1. I wonder why people downvoted this question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First take a bangla unicode supported font like:

```
Font banglaFont=new Font("Arial Unicode MS", Font.BOLD,15);
```

Then attach it to your JTextArea object using setFont

```
text1.setFont(banglaFont);
```

Now you should be able to view bangla properly, give a try.

**NOTE:** Java uses font from the system , so if the system doesn't contain a specific font then you can deploy that font within your application using Font.createFont().

Comment: Arial Unicode MS is just an example, you can use any custom font with Bangla support.

Comment: @Imran Rana please you forgot to answering (@ Andrew Thompson) question about Font supports on *nix and apple OSX

Comment: @AndrewThompson Java uses font from the system , so if the system doesn't contain a specific font then you can deploy that font within your application using Font.createFont().

Comment: *"you can deploy that font within your application.."*  It might be a good idea to mention that in the answer, since any font ending in MS would not typically be installed on an OS X or *nix machine. ;)

Comment: *"so if the system doesn't contain a specific font then you can deploy that font within your application"* Presuming you have the right to distribute that font at all. Which, in the case of an MS font, I can almost guarantee you don't.